# Instance variable (NSString) wont change in custom class

Tags: macos, cocoa

I've created a class to control an NSOutlineView and that class comunicate with my AppDelegate using notification. This class that controls the behavior of the outlineview is initialized using awakefromnib so that header is added immediately (my will), while later by calling a method of this class is populated by children. Everything works ok, but when is the moment to create a notification for my AppleDelegate I discover that instance variable is null while at the time of the initial call was ok.

```
    @interface MyClass : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSTextViewDelegate, NSTextFieldDelegate, NSOutlineViewDelegate, NSOutlineViewDataSource>
{
    NSString * _plistPath;
}

@implementation MyClass

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(& once, ^{
        self.Outline.delegate = self;
        self.Outline.dataSource = self;
        self.Outline.floatsGroupRows = NO;
        [_treeController addObject: @{@"title": @"Model list", @"isLeaf": @(NO)}.mutableCopy];
        [self.Outline expandItem:[self.Outline itemAtRow:0]];
        [self.Outline selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] byExtendingSelection:NO];

        // Enable Drag and Drop
        [self.Outline registerForDraggedTypes: [NSArray arrayWithObject: @"public.text"]];
    });
}

- (void)loadPlist:(NSDictionary *)dict path:(NSString *)path
{
    _plistPath = path;
    NSLog(@"at loadPlist _plistPath = %@, self is = %@", _plistPath, self); // here is ok!
}

// Here all the NSOutlineViewDelegate methods
// .....

// finally after editing value in the interface using the outline view
// and some field attacched to the tree controller..
// I need to notificate AppleDelegate for the changes made to the plist,
//reindicating the path stored in _plistPath variable..but:

- (void)update
{

    NSMutableArray *List = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSInteger rows = [_Outline numberOfRows];
    NSInteger i;
    i = 0;
    while (i != rows) {
        id obj = [_Outline itemAtRow:i];
        if (i != 0) {
            Tree *entry = (Tree *)(((NSTreeNode *)obj).representedObject);

            if (entry.title.length > 0    && ![entry.title isEqualToString:kNullString]
                && entry.size.length > 0  && ![entry.size isEqualToString:kNullString]
                && entry.model.length > 0 && ![entry.model isEqualToString:kNullString]
                && entry.year.length > 0  && ![entry.year isEqualToString:kNullString]) {

                NSMutableDictionary *childDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                [childDict setObject:entry.title forKey:@"Name"];
                [childDict setObject:entry.size forKey:@"Size"];
                [childDict setObject:entry.model forKey:@"Model"];
                [childDict setObject:entry.year forKey:@"Year"];

                [List addObject:childDict];
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *uf = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSLog(@"at update _plistPath = %@, self is = %@", _plistPath, self); // this time here is nil....

    [uf setObject:_plistPath forKey:@"path"]; // here crash because _plistPath is nil
    [uf setObject:List forKey:@"dictionary"];

    NSNotification *note = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"UpdatePlist" object:_Outline userInfo:uf];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:note];

}
```

basically at the second time I need "_plistPath" value is nil (I have some very specific reasons for sending to MyClass the original path and then return it back to the sender (ie AppleDelegate)) and I have more instance variables declared in MyClass that works well..so I can't understand why. Any suggestion?

EDIT
As requested by @matt I change the NSLog including "self"

then the output is that:

```
2015-05-11 22:06:36.433 TestApp[24990:56140] at loadPlist _plistPath = /Volumes/DATI/test.plist, self is = <MyClass: 0x600000127760>
2015-05-11 22:07:08.552 TestApp[24990:56140] at update _plistPath = (null), self is = <MyClass: 0x608000125c80>
```

Comment: "NSApplicationDelegate" is not needed, is only an error copying..

Comment: Please show the actual logging output in full - thanks!

Comment: Also, with each log, please log `self` so we know this is the same instance throughout.

Comment: Using dispatch_once the way you are is highly dangerous. That initialisation won't happen if your view is unloaded and loaded again. And if it isn't unloaded and loaded again, dispatch_once is pointless.

Comment: @matt, done, code updated with new logs + output.

Comment: @gnasher729 "awakeFromNib" is called multiple times populating the NSOutlineView, and thanks for the suggestion but not is the problem (I hope). Adding multiple init methods is not the problem :)

Comment: Different instance... initialization problem... then @gnasher729 forgot what I said :) ha ha ha

Comment: I am left wondering if the caller that is sending the `*path` into `_loadPlist` is releasing that memory.  Frankly, I can't recall off of the top of my head if `NSString *string1 = string2` is the proper way to copy an NSString or if it only copies the pointer and updates the reference count or not.

Comment: the var is not leaking, is simply nil. I need to implement a real "init-with" method, and test it..

Comment: Thank you for the logs - you have confirmed what I suspected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log shows the problem:

```
at loadPlist _plistPath = /Volumes/DATI/test.plist, 
    self is = <MyClass: 0x600000127760>
at update _plistPath = (null), 
    self is = <MyClass: 0x608000125c80>
```

These are two difference instances of MyClass. But `plistPath` is an instance variable - so it can perfectly reasonably have a value in one instance and be nil in another instance.

Comment: Now you need to think about _why_ these are two different instances. But that is not what you asked. You said you couldn't understand why `plistPath` was nil "the second time"; now you can: it's a different variable in a different instance.

Comment: It is so. Yet the code has not been modified, but the two instanse opened my eyes, so simply I'll insert the init code leaving awakefromnib. thanks

Comment: Update. awakeFromNib it is still there but without dispatch_once_t (used a trick if objects are not initialized), but using notification to cummunicate with classes is simply "SUPER", so I can use the only and initial instance of self.... and everything seem works great. Thanks again @matt and thanks also to gnasher729 :-)